# iOS: Can I offer an in app purchase as free for a period of time?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm close to uploading my next app. And during the first month I would like to offer one of my in app purchases as "pre-installed" to get enough downloads. I mean it should be as if the user already bought it. Is there a way to do this? After the first month new users should need to pay for it but existing users still should have it free.

Comment: you should use a backend to verify in-app-purchases anyways. then it should be no problem to handle these cases there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in iTunes Connect. You will have to create an in-app purchase for your unlock. You can then increase/decrease the price for a certain amount of time. Go to the in-app-ourchase in iTunes Connect and click the Edit button.